# Is it expected that coredns pods look or know the network DNS real IP?

Tags: networking, routing, kubernetes

I created a cluster on bare metal, set up with one laptop as the control plane and another laptop as a worker node, for learning purposes.
They're in a local lan with a home router.

After a couple of tutorials that went smooth, I started having connectivity / networking issues, and looking on the net brought up more questions than answers.

Now my CoreDNS pods keep crashing: is it expected that they know about the lan router IP (external to the cluster)? Because this is inside one of their logs:

```
vaio-sve151:~$ kubectl logs -n kube-system    coredns-bd6b6df9f-6t25z
[WARNING] plugin/kubernetes: starting server with unsynced Kubernetes API
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = db32ca3650231d74073ff4cf814959a7
CoreDNS-1.8.6
linux/amd64, go1.17.1, 13a9191
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 3471238297657131622.6520009371282614310. HINFO: read udp 10.244.1.43:57243->10.8.191.167:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 3471238297657131622.6520009371282614310. HINFO: read udp 10.244.1.43:58513->10.8.191.167:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 3471238297657131622.6520009371282614310. HINFO: read udp 10.244.1.43:57970->10.8.191.167:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 3471238297657131622.6520009371282614310. HINFO: read udp 10.244.1.43:37901->10.8.191.167:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 3471238297657131622.6520009371282614310. HINFO: read udp 10.244.1.43:55314->10.8.191.167:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 3471238297657131622.6520009371282614310. HINFO: read udp 10.244.1.43:56356->10.8.191.167:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 3471238297657131622.6520009371282614310. HINFO: read udp 10.244.1.43:51310->10.8.191.167:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 3471238297657131622.6520009371282614310. HINFO: read udp 10.244.1.43:39135->10.8.191.167:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 3471238297657131622.6520009371282614310. HINFO: read udp 10.244.1.43:57516->10.8.191.167:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 3471238297657131622.6520009371282614310. HINFO: read udp 10.244.1.43:49389->10.8.191.167:53: i/o timeout
[INFO] SIGTERM: Shutting down servers then terminating
[INFO] plugin/health: Going into lameduck mode for 5s
```

My setup:

```
@vaio-sve151:~$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME            STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION    INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
thinkpad-x260   Ready    <none>                 2d19h   v1.23.17   10.8.191.148   <none>        Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS   5.15.0-73-generic   containerd://1.7.2
vaio-sve151     Ready    control-plane,master   2d19h   v1.23.17   10.8.191.138   <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS   5.4.0-150-generic   containerd://1.7.2
```

The router (Linksys EA3500) acts as DNS:

```
@vaio-sve151:~$ nslookup 10.8.191.167
167.191.8.10.in-addr.arpa       name = Linksys44105.lan.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

Pods:

```
vaio-sve151:~$ kubectl get pods -A -o wide
NAMESPACE      NAME                                   READY   STATUS             RESTARTS         AGE     IP             NODE            NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default        bash                                   1/1     Running            1 (3h29m ago)    3h32m   10.244.1.42    thinkpad-x260   <none>           <none>
default        kubernetes-bootcamp-65d5b99f84-7zqwb   1/1     Running            0                4h3m    10.244.1.37    thinkpad-x260   <none>           <none>
default        kubernetes-bootcamp-65d5b99f84-9bm48   1/1     Running            0                4h3m    10.244.1.35    thinkpad-x260   <none>           <none>
default        kubernetes-bootcamp-65d5b99f84-h69ps   1/1     Running            0                4h3m    10.244.1.36    thinkpad-x260   <none>           <none>
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-8tv8v                  1/1     Running            1 (3h7m ago)     3h17m   10.8.191.138   vaio-sve151     <none>           <none>
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-tlzz6                  1/1     Running            0                3h17m   10.8.191.148   thinkpad-x260   <none>           <none>
kube-system    coredns-bd6b6df9f-6t25z                0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   49 (4m28s ago)   3h28m   10.244.1.43    thinkpad-x260   <none>           <none>
kube-system    coredns-bd6b6df9f-8qzs4                0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   49 (65s ago)     3h47m   10.244.1.41    thinkpad-x260   <none>           <none>
kube-system    etcd-vaio-sve151                       1/1     Running            17 (3h7m ago)    2d19h   10.8.191.138   vaio-sve151     <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-apiserver-vaio-sve151             1/1     Running            1 (3h7m ago)     4h26m   10.8.191.138   vaio-sve151     <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-vaio-sve151    1/1     Running            1 (3h7m ago)     4h25m   10.8.191.138   vaio-sve151     <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-proxy-mgzrm                       1/1     Running            1 (3h7m ago)     4h17m   10.8.191.138   vaio-sve151     <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-proxy-npwrh                       1/1     Running            0                4h17m   10.8.191.148   thinkpad-x260   <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-scheduler-vaio-sve151             1/1     Running            1 (3h7m ago)     4h24m   10.8.191.138   vaio-sve151     <none>           <none>
```

All the services:

```
@vaio-sve151:~$  kubectl get services -A -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE     SELECTOR
default       kubernetes            ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP                  2d19h   <none>
default       kubernetes-bootcamp   NodePort    10.101.18.12   <none>        8080:32682/TCP           3h11m   app=kubernetes-bootcamp
kube-system   kube-dns              ClusterIP   10.96.0.10     <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   2d19h   k8s-app=kube-dns
```

Is it normal that a pod like `coredns-bd6b6df9f-6t25z` has the router IP `10.8.191.167` in its log?